# Iterating across subsets of collections

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have a collection of data objects (say `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`).

```
require(xts)
set.seed(1)
x1 <- xts(data.frame(replicate(6, sample(c(1:10), 10, rep = T))), Sys.Date() + 1:10)
x2 <- xts(data.frame(replicate(6, sample(c(1:10), 10, rep = T))), Sys.Date() + 1:10)
x3 <- xts(data.frame(replicate(6, sample(c(1:10), 10, rep = T))), Sys.Date() + 1:10)
```

They all have the same number of columns.  I wish to find statistical summaries of subsets of these collections. I have figured out how to do this for the case that i want all elements with `lapply`: I use the function `colSummary` below.

```
colSummary <- function(ff)
{
    lapply(1:ncol(x1), function(X) apply(cbind(x1[,X], x2[,X], x3[,X]), 1, ff))
}

summary <- colSummary(`mean`)
names(summary) <- colnames(x1)
```

I would like to be able to find the same summaries for subsets -- by passing in an argument such as `varList1` or varList2`to`colSummary`.

```
varList1 <- c('x1', 'x3')
varList2 <- c('x2', 'x3')
```

I have played about with `do.call` and nested `lapply` but cannot figure out how to alter `colSummary` such that the `cbind(...)` is replaced with a reference to an object list (such as `varList1`) that I pass into the function.

The desired function would return the same output as the following function when i passed in `varList1`.

```
colSummary^ <- function(ff)
{
    lapply(1:ncol(x1), function(X) apply(cbind(x1[,X], x3[,X]), 1, ff))
}
```

And when passed in `varList2` would return the same output as the above function `colSummary^` with `apply(cbind(x2[,X], x3[,X])` substituted in place of the `apply(cbind(x1[,X], x3[,X])` in `colSummary^`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `varList1` in your `lapply` call rather than `1:ncol(x1)`. `[` accepts character input to match the [row|col]names of an object.

```
colSummary <- function(ff,vars=NULL)
{
  if (is.null(vars)) vars <- names(x1)
  sapply(vars, function(X) apply(cbind(x1[,X], x2[,X], x3[,X]), 1, ff),simplify=FALSE)
}

colSummary("mean",c("X1","X3"))
$X1
2014-01-10 2014-01-11 2014-01-12 2014-01-13 2014-01-14 2014-01-15 2014-01-16 2014-01-17 2014-01-18 2014-01-19 
  5.333333   4.333333   4.666667   6.000000   2.666667   8.000000   3.000000   4.666667   3.000000   5.333333 

$X3
2014-01-10 2014-01-11 2014-01-12 2014-01-13 2014-01-14 2014-01-15 2014-01-16 2014-01-17 2014-01-18 2014-01-19 
  7.666667   6.666667   7.333333   2.666667   6.333333   6.333333   5.333333   5.333333   6.333333   6.000000
```

Note I've also used `sapply` with `simplify=FALSE` to give you the same output, but with the list elements named.

**Edit**

With the clarifications, I believe this is what you want. You can use `mget` to obtain variables using the names.

```
colSummary <- function(ff,vars=NULL)
{
  if (is.null(vars)) vars <- c("x1","x2","x3")
  sapply(names(x1),
    function(X) apply(
       do.call(cbind,lapply(mget(vars,.GlobalEnv),"[",,X)),
     1, ff),
  simplify=FALSE)
}
```

Use of `mget` and `get` is sometimes seen as un-R-like - you are better off passing your data into your function, ie:

```
colSummary <- function(ff,vars)
{      
  sapply(names(vars[[1]]),
    function(X) apply(
       do.call(cbind,lapply(vars,"[",,X)),
     1, ff),
  simplify=FALSE)
}
```

and call with

```
colSummary("mean",list(x1,x3))
```

Comment: +1 for the `sapply( ... , simplify=F)` trick, but i think my ambigious question has tripped you up. I'm trying to change the `apply(cbind(x1[,X], x2[,X], x3[,X])` to `apply(cbind(x1[,X], x3[,X])` when i pass in `varList1`, etc. I have edited to question to make this clearer.